# Creating a backup and getting error only concenate list and not (str)

Tags: python, backup

I'm trying to write a code to create backup of files or directory using Python but there is an error : can only concenate list not "str"
Here's my code :

```
import os
import time

# The files or directory which has to be backed up
source = ['"F:\\College Stuffs"']

#The backup must be stored in a target directory
target_dir = ['"E:\\Backup"']

#File will be backed up in a zip file and name will be set to current date

target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + target.append('.zip')

# Create the directory if it's not present

if not os.path.exists(target_dir): 
    os.mkdir(target_dir) #Make the directory

#Use zip command to put files in a zip archive

zip_command = "zip -r {} {}".format(target,''.join(source))

#run the backuo
print "Zip command is : "
print zip_command
print "Running:"
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print 'Successful backup to', target
else:
    print 'Backup FAILED'
```

Comment: what is `target` here

Comment: Why are your file paths quoted? e.g. `'"E:\\Backup"'`, you probably mean `'E:\\Backup'`

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a `list`

```
#The backup must be stored in a target directory
target_dir = ['"E:\\Backup"']
```

while your usage indicates you'd intended to use a `str` there:

```
#The backup must be stored in a target directory
target_dir = '"E:\\Backup"'
```